# How can I put declarative syntax inside a Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins

I can use the "[script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script)" function to put some Scripted-style pipeline code inside a declarative pipeline, but is the opposite possible?

Is there a Groovy function I can use that I can use to put Declarative-style code inside a scripted pipeline?

The reason I want this, there's some some things easier to express in Declarative (e.g. parallel), and there's a bunch of things that are easy to do in Scripted, but seem to be impossible in declarative (e.g. loops). I'd like to compose both of those kinds of features together.